# Testing Gigabit network

Tags: networking

I wonder, if wiring for 10/100 and 1000 is same, how can the following lan cable tester detect the difference between them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX use pairs 2 and 3. 1000BASE-T uses all four pairs. Thus a simple tester can see if pairs 1 and 4 are crossed. Notice that the tester does not have indicators to differentiate between straight-through cables for 100BASE-T and 1000BASE-T as the connections are identical.

Comment: Basically a very simple tester which will instead show pin-to-pin connectivity should be enough to test cat6 cable wiring?

Comment: @Pablo: A very simple tester will only find very simple faults. It won't tell you whether the cable is good enough to be certified Cat6. It can't test for crosstalk and other electrical characteristics, just for som obvious shorts, breaks and miswiring. It may be adequate for your needs, only you can tell.

Comment: Yes I understand about quality measurement, but what I mean at least it(cat5 tester) can determine wiring mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic tester and will mainly show wiring errors.  It may show that the cable is technically capable of gigbit, a more advanced tester may provide better results.

At least you would see mis-wired cables and cables that are not punched down/crimped properly

Answer (score 0):

This tester uses and base unit and a remote unit to connect to both ends of the connected cable. As such, it will test the capabilities of the cable. It does not take into account whether the devices you'll connect to the cable will be able to handle any given speed.

For instance, while the cable may be capable of Gigabit connections (Cat5e or Cat6, acceptable length, low enough noise on the line, low interference, etc), connecting a 10/100 NIC to either end of the cable will obviously then only provide the connection up to the capabilities of the equipment connected to it.